# Buffered Writer Java Limit / Issues

Tags: java, text, bufferedwriter, writer

I have a buffered writer that is writing to a text file. For some reason the writer stops writing a long string about half way through. Are there any known issues with using the buffered Writer in java?

Comment: Did you check the doc or the source to see if there is a limit to the size of the buffer?

Comment: flush() the stream before calling close().

Comment: The problem is most likely in your particular implementation.  Please post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @nickecarlo, `close()` calls flush for you...

Comment: @Lucas Of course it does. Thank you. I should take my own advice on here and read the documentation a bit more carefully.

Comment: closed it already, it has to be an issue somewhere else in my code

Comment: @Eric Callan - If you still expect any help then please **post the relevant part of your code**.

Answer (score 6):

Are you closing the writer?

```
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before writing large text into file, use obj_BufferedWriter.flush().