# BufferedWriter Stops Writing

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am trying to rewrite this dictionary: [dictionary.txt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt) sorted by length instead by alphabetical order. I have the following code (inside main(String[] args)):

```
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(DIC_READ_PATH)));
    BufferedWriter write= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(DIC_WRITE_PATH),1);
    ArrayList<String> toWrite = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int a = read.read(); a != -1; a = read.read()){
        char c = (char) a;
        toWrite.add("" + c + read.readLine());
    }
    read.close();
    Collections.sort(toWrite, new MyComparator());
    for (int a = 0; a <= 70000; a += 10000){
        write.write(toWrite.subList(a, a + 10000).toString().replaceAll("[\\[,\\]]", "").replaceAll(" ", "\n"));
        write.flush();
    }

    write.write(toWrite.subList(80000, toWrite.size()).toString().replaceAll("[\\[,\\]]", "").replaceAll(" ", "\n"));
    write.close();
```

MyComparator:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
@Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.length() == arg1.length()){
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1); 
        } 
        return arg0.length() < arg1.length() ? -1 : +1;
    }
}
```

It sorts the Arraylist fine, but when I write the Strings, it doesn't write 8 words. I tried varying the buffer on the BufferedWriter and found that smaller Buffers help, so I put a Buffer of 1. I found this: [Buffered Writer Java Limit / Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623374/buffered-writer-java-limit-issues) and tried flushing every time I write and closing at the end (even varied Buffer afterwards). I still get 80360 words instead of 80368. Why won't it write the full list of words? Do I have to use another BufferedWriter? If so, how can I use it without it overwriting what is already writen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are consuming random characters of your input data:

```
for (int a = read.read(); a != -1; a = read.read()){
```

don't mix `read()` and `readLine()` calls.  just use `readLine()` and test for null.

also, to write your results, don't use the List.toString impl and nasty regex replacements, just loop over the list and write one word followed by a newline.

Comment: no characters are consumed (a is cast to char), but that might be a good idea.

Comment: I agree that this is a bad practice, but imho that is another problem. The real "missing 8" problem is the missing new lines.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu - yes, characters are consumed.  your words are probably missing their first characters.

Comment: @GáborBakos - yes, but using the simple look over the list will also solve the problem.

Comment: @jtahlborn right after the `for(int a = read.read(); a != -1; a = read.read()){` there is `char c = (char) a;` and the string added to the ArrayList is `c + read.readLine()`. Because a is cast into a char which is then put into the string, no characters are lost. I did it that way so that I can do something if the first character is some symbol.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu - ah, missed the part where you prepended that char back on.  still, better not to mix `read()` and `readLine()`.

Comment: @jtahlborn the only reason why I do that is so that I can cause something to happen if the first character on a line is something, but I should do it with just a `readLine()` if I don't care about it.

Comment: Was this really the cause of the problem? Why did this caused missing 8 words? (I assumed the number of words to write was checked at some point of development.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
 for (int a = 0; a <= 70000; a += 10000){
        write.write(toWrite.subList(a, a + 10000).toString().replaceAll("[\\[,\\]]", "").replaceAll(" ", "\n"));
        write.flush();
    }
```

You should write.write("\n"); before flush.

Comment: If you look at the end, each ' ' is replaced by '\n', so no write.write("\n") is needed

Comment: But there will be no space at the end. ;) Isn't it interesting that exactly 8 iterations are there?